I'm getting this error when trying to run Friday Night Funkin'
I wanted to know if I was doing something wrong or this was an issue with the file I downloaded (I got it from the game's itch.io page)
Commands I used:
cd Downloads

cd funkin-linux-64bit

./Funkin

Error:
" ./Funkin: error while loading shared libraries: libvlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory "

The libvlc.so.5 file is provided by the libvlc5 package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install libvlc5 in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:
sudo apt install libvlc5

